# Http POST verb returns null value "realtor_id" violates not-null constraint when serializing data from model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have been trying to serialize data from my real estate web-app but whenever i make http POST request to the backend it returns null value in column `realtor_id` violates not-null constraint. can someone help me resolve this issue.

models.py

```
class Listing(models.Model):
      realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      description = models.TextField(blank=True)
      price = models.IntegerField()
      bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
      bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
      garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
      sqft = models.IntegerField()
      lot_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
      photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
      photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
      photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
      photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
      photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
      photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
      photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
      is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
      def __str__(self):
          return self.title
```

serializer.py

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
     title = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
     address = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
     city = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
     state = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
     zipcode = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
     price = serializers.IntegerField()
     bedrooms = serializers.IntegerField()
     bathrooms = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
     garage = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
     sqft = serializers.IntegerField()
     lot_size = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
     description = serializers.CharField()
     list_date = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Realtor
         fields = ['name']


   def create(self, validated_data):
         return Listing.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Update method for serializer.py

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.realtor = validated_data.get('realtor',  instance.Realtor.name)
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
    instance.city = validated_data.get('city', instance.city)
    instance.state = validated_data.get('state', instance.state)
    instance.zipcode = validated_data.get('zipcode', instance.zipcode)
    instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
    instance.description = validated_data.get('list_date', instance.list_date)
    instance.price = validated_data.get('price', instance.price)
    instance.bedrooms = validated_data.get('bedrooms', instance.bedrooms)
    instance.bathrooms = validated_data.get('bathrooms', instance.bathrooms)
    instance.garage = validated_data.get('garage', instance.garage)
    instance.sqft = validated_data.get('sqft', instance.sqft)
    instance.lot_size = validated_data.get('lot_size', instance.lot_size)

    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Could it be that my update method is the cause of this error?

Comment: Please add full error traceback. And it would be helpful to see the request body which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

`instance.realtor = validated_data.get('realtor',       instance.Realtor.name)` ... realtor is a foreign key but here you reference a name

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass full instance of `Realtor` instead of `instance.Realtor.name` like this

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.realtor = validated_data.get('realtor',  instance.Realtor)
```